# how to get Fragment's package name (not Activity's) in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-package-managers

I'm using some different kinds of data in my application and I've categorized them by package name like (movies,animations,...). is there is any way to access fragment's package name?!

i tried `fragment.getActivity().getPackageName()` but it returns Activity's package name

Comment: try with  getContext()

Comment: still returns Activity's package name! @vikaskumar

Comment: @herrmartell no, I've seen it before, that's about Activity's Package name too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print the full name of the class with package

```
fragment.getClass().getPackage().getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, this will return Fragment name along with package name

```
this.getClass().getName();
```

You can replace your fragment class name and get only package name, your final method should look like this.

```
private String getPackageName() {
    return this.getClass().getName().replace("."+this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"");
}
```